# MediaPipe Selfie Segmentation results are not invoking when moved to other Chrome tabs

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, mediapipe

```
const videoElement =document.getElementsByClassName('input_video')[0];
selfieSegmentationObj = new SelfieSegmentation({locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/selfie_segmentation/${file}`;
    }});
selfieSegmentationObj.setOptions({
    modelSelection: 1,
    selfieMode: false,
    effect: 'mask',
});

selfieSegmentationObj.onResults(selfieSegmentationResults);

cameraObj = new Camera(videoElement, {
    onFrame: async () => {
    await selfieSegmentationObj.send({image: videoElement});
    },
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
});

cameraObj.start();


function selfieSegmentationResults(results) {
    const canvasElement = document.getElementsByClassName('output_canvas')[0];
    var canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
    canvasCtx.save();
    canvasCtx.drawImage(results.segmentationMask, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
}
```

When we moved from one tab to another tab then callback function "selfieSegmentationResults" is not getting called from the SelfieSegmentation object.

Please, someone, help if there is any other solution that can get the segmented image data even if we moved to another Chrome tab.

Comment: Hi ! I'm trying to solve the same issue, could you find a solution ?

Comment: @Hollyol I mentioned my inputs in the below link. Please refer, https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3018

Answer (score 1):

Selfisegmentation might be using requestAnimationFrame under the hood which only works in the active tab.

The same thing was happening to me. I was building a background removing app with selfisegmentation and whenever I switched the tab, it stopped on the last frame. I solved it by using web workers.

Comment: Hi @ameed-faridi ! Can you elaborate on how to use web workers ?
I researched that too, but [it seems like mediapipe's selfie segmentation doesn't work in workers](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/3659)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: inputVideoElement.addEventListener("play", () => {
      async function step() {
        await selfieSegmentation.send({ image: inputVideoElement });
      }

Comment: then

 worker.onmessage = function (e) {
        step();
        worker.postMessage("start");
      };

       worker.postMessage("start");